# How to Reduce Code Duplication between SDK and CLI

Tags: c#, api, architecture, sdk, command-line-interface

I have a REST/Streaming API that I'd like to provide a CLI and C# SDK for. I'm thinking about the implementation of both modules and trying to avoid duplicating logic in both. This leads me to ask:

Is it typical for an SDK to be a language-specific wrapper for CLI calls to avoid duplicating logic? Is there any standard practice for structuring the relationship between a CLI and SDK(s).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the client SDK to develop the CLI ? This way, your wouldn't have any code duplication.

Comment: Can you justify any benefits to developing the CLI from the SDK or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, the main benefit is exactly what you ask for, avoiding code duplication. The CLI is a client like any other, it makes complete sense to use the SDK to develop it to levarage in the CLI the functions to interact with the API provided by the SDK